# In SQL, what's the best way to convert a single value to multiple rows of output?

Tags: sql, oracle

This should be an easy one.

I have a table with rows:

```
CREATE TABLE FURNITURE
       (ROOM VARCHAR2(50) CONSTRAINT PK_DEPT PRIMARY KEY,
        APPLIANCE VARCHAR2(50));
INSERT INTO FURNITURE VALUES
        ('BEDROOM','BED');
INSERT INTO FURNITURE VALUES
        ('LIVING ROOM', 'SOFA');
INSERT INTO FURNITURE VALUES
        ('TV ROOM', 'TV');
INSERT INTO FURNITURE VALUES
        ('ALL', 'LAMP');
```

The desired output is:

| Room | Appliance |
| --- | --- |
| BEDROOM | BED |
| BEDROOM | LAMP |
| LIVING ROOM | SOFA |
| LIVING ROOM | LAMP |
| TV ROOM | TV |
| TV ROOM | LAMP |

(sorting doesn't matter).

I have one very naive way of doing it:

```
select f1.room,
       f1.appliance
  from furniture f1 where room <> 'ALL'
 union
select all_rooms.room,
       f2.appliance
  from furniture f2
cross join
       (select distinct room from furniture where room <> 'ALL') all_rooms
 where f2.room = 'ALL';
```

Surely there's a better way?

I was trying to come up with a solution using CROSS APPLY but I'm failing.

SQL Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0db734/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the rooms and then use an `INNER JOIN` to the furniture:

```sql
SELECT r.room,
       f.appliance
FROM   (SELECT room FROM furniture WHERE room <> 'ALL') r
       INNER JOIN furniture f
       ON (r.room = f.room OR f.room = 'ALL')
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ROOM | APPLIANCE |
| --- | --- |
| BEDROOM | LAMP |
| LIVING ROOM | LAMP |
| TV ROOM | LAMP |
| BEDROOM | BED |
| LIVING ROOM | SOFA |
| TV ROOM | TV |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iKfXGcB4)

Comment: This one seems the easiest to understand without analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT f1.ROOM, f2.APPLIANCE
FROM FURNITURE f1 INNER JOIN FURNITURE f2
ON (f2.ROOM = f1.ROOM AND f2.APPLIANCE = f1.APPLIANCE) OR f2.ROOM = 'ALL'
WHERE f1.ROOM <> 'ALL';
```

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6be763/1).

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN` and not `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @MT0 I don't know why it seemed at the moment I thought about it that it would include any possible nulls in APPLIANCE, but it does not. I edited.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got CROSS APPLY to work...although it doesn't work in the fiddle, because CROSS APPLY isn't available until Oracle 12:

```
SELECT all_rooms.room,
       f1.appliance
  FROM furniture f1
 CROSS apply (SELECT DISTINCT f2.room
                FROM furniture f2
               WHERE f2.room <> 'ALL'
                 AND (f1.room = f2.room OR f1.room = 'ALL')) all_rooms;
```